# How can I fix } expected error in Unity C#?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a little problem with my C# code, so I have this simple PlayerHealth code here and Unity always gives me this error: [Unity Bracket Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr232.png)

**Code:**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 100;
    public float damage = 10;


    void OnCollisionEnter(otherObj Collision) {
        if (otherObj.tag == "Bullet") {
            health = health - damage;
            if (health < 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I appreciate your help! :D**

Comment: syntax error I see is: the function parameter type and name should be inversed: this should be `fun(type name)` and not `fun(name type)`. (as for a variable declaration)

Comment: your code would not compile but for different reasons - you seem to have the parameter type and name switched (`OnCollisionEnter(Collision otherObj)`. My guess (if this is your actual code) is that the unknown type is throwing off the parser and cascading into other errors.

Comment: @Pac0 `gameObject` is a property of one of the base classes, so I removed that part of my comment

Comment: Thanks, It was *OnCollisionEnter(Collision otherObj)*. Thank you @DStanley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnCollisionEnter.html) function, the parameter is wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float health = 100f;
    public float damage = 10f;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision otherObj) 
    {
        if (otherObj.gameObject.tag == "Bullet") 
        {
            health = health - damage;
            if (health < 0)
            {
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```